# The schema in this data file must match the datasource : Amazon Machine Learning

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning

When i create a model (regression) using Amazon Machine Learning,  i provide a datasource with some schema. The data source contains some values along with the target attribute. Then the data source is splitted in 70-30 for training and evaluation of model and they still need target attribute with values in it. As the data will be used for training first and then for evaluation so the target attribute is required, this much i understand.

Now come to the batch prediction part. In this also i have to provide a datasource and i understand that the schema have to be similar to the schema which is used to train the model, so again the target attribute is required but why the values are required in this part i do not understand. If i provide a dataset with similar schema and no data in target attribute it gives me

```
 The schema in this data file must match the datasource used to create the ML model ml-KSc8japCCo0. Ensure that the data file you are using matches the schema structure.
```

When i use the same schema with same model but with values in target attribute everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You needs to provide a batch with all the values to make the prediction less the field to predict; for example,

I used this structure to make de model and the training, select seconds_taken like a target

```
serial,operator,station,phase,next_phase,seconds
123,Jack,Machine 1,Phase 1,Phase 2,230528
```

The goal is make a prediction about how many time is gonna take to pass from the first phase to another with a different values of operator and station, to detect better performance on the company.

Select your evaluation on the Machine Learning Dashboard

Machine Learning -> Batch Predictions -> Create batch prediction

This is the structure to make a prediction:

```
serial,operator,station,phase,next_phase
123,Benn,Machine 1,Phase 1,Phase 2
123,Jhon,Machine 1,Phase 1,Phase 2
123,Benn,Machine 2,Phase 1,Phase 2
123,Jhon,Machine 2,Phase 1,Phase 2
```

Take care on the titles, I got the same error if I use this structure

```
serial,operator,station,phase,next_phase,seconds
123,Benn,Machine 1,Phase 1,Phase 2
123,Jhon,Machine 1,Phase 1,Phase 2
123,Benn,Machine 2,Phase 1,Phase 2
123,Jhon,Machine 2,Phase 1,Phase 2
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning here that if you had to change any data types after importing the data source, you can't just create a new data source during ML model creation; you'll have to create a data source separately, and then create your ML model.

Comment: Thank you @K.Carpenter! That was it for me :)